# rendering template with csrf token and template context

Tags: django, django-views, csrf

Currently I am rendering HTML views with the following syntax:

```
t = loader.get_template('sometemplate.html')
c = Context ({
    'title': title,
    'content': conent,
})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I want to add a form with CSRF protection in my view. What should I change in my syntax so I can pass both context and the token to render view?

The [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) show a different approach for rendering a view with CSRF token in it, but there is no additional context passed in these examples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use RequestContext instead of Context? Also, you can just use render_to_response instead of returning a HttpResponse:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('sometemplate.html', { 'title': title, 'content': content }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```